# RTE markup and Page Layout javascript error

Tags: 2010, jquery, ribbon, access-denied

Okay, so I have been running into this issue way too often now and it's starting to really irritate me and I have no idea what triggers these errors.

I have made a custom masterpage for my SharePoint site. When I add a CEWP and want to select a markup for some selected text, the markup dropdown doesn't show. I use my Developertool to debug and it throws me an Access Denied error on the javascript for the Markup.

I tried googling the issue, and I tried the various solutions presented for me.

1. Set site as trusted site **Failed**
2. Remove jQuery definitions and use SharePoint's own **Failed**
3. Remove empty javascript files referenced in the masterpage/pagelayouts **Failed**
4. Set jQuery.NoConflict(); **Failed**
5. Remove SecurityTrimmedControl from Ribbon (if there are any) **Failed**
6. Remove all references to custom javascript files **Failed**

So now I'm kicked back to square one...

Everything of course works if I try using the default.master or v4.master. No issues there. But as soon as I use my custom masterpage, some of the core Ribbon functions are disabled because of this "Access Denied" error I get in the javascript code.

A lot of people on the answers I found on google talked about this issue coming from a "cross domain" problem on the site, which I highly doubt is the problem as there is only one domain present on the entire server (no cluster).

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and how did you solve it?

Thank you

Comment: If you switch back to v4.master does your page then work? If so what's the difference in Script tags if you view source?

Comment: @PerJakobsen There are no difference. They are the same, of course mine has some additional `<script>` tags due to my customization. But I tried stripping those but still with the same error in the Ribbon.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see which request is giving the access denied?

Comment: @PerJakobsen I don't know how to use Fiddler. I know that it's this line `$v_2.open('GET', $p0, true)` in this javascript function `RTE.StyleRuleUtility.$El_0 = function($p0)` in sp.ui.rte.debug.js file which causes the error.

Comment: If you do anything with AJAX, then you should use fiddler, just run it at the same time as IE and it'll show you all requests send to the server and you can see the url of the one causing a 403

Comment: @PerJakobsen Fiddler doesn't seem to pick it up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error.

I forgot that I had 2 custom fonts implemented, which I link to in my masterpage's header, and they of course link to external URLs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<external path like http://google.com/g.css>" />
```

And since the Ribbon Markups dropdown, as well as Styles dropdown both look through all CSS file references present on the current page and Data source access on cross-domains are deactivated by default in Internet Explorer, it makes sense that an Access Denied is thrown.

Downloading the CSS'es and hosting them locally fixed my issue.